# Change element name without change in namespace

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I think this is tricky. I want the below xml, with getpositionrouter element changed to 'newelement'. The thing is, this should be the only change in the output from the input. That is even the namespace 'pos', should be preserved. So in the input instead of pos it can be ns1="positionNS". Then output also ns1, should be there.

```
input


<pos:getPositionRouter xmlns:pos="positionNS">
   <positionID>
      <code>1</code>
   </positionID>
   <parameter>?</parameter>
</pos:getPositionRouter>
```

desired output

```
<pos:newelement xmlns:pos="positionNS">
   <positionID>
      <code>1</code>
   </positionID>
   <parameter>?</parameter>
</pos:newelement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if following stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pos="positionNS">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="pos:getPositionRouter" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pos:getPositionRouter">
        <pos:newElement>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() |  @*" />
        </pos:newElement>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() |  @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This will always have the namespace as pos. As i said in my question, it can be ns1 or anything. That should be completely dependent on the input xml.

Comment: Right I missed that. In this case I'm afraid this is going beyong the xslt 1.0 (and probably of 2.0 too). I tried to do it using `xsl:namespace-alias` but the problem is it is not possible to fill attributes of top-level elements are not interpreted. The other issue is you have to declare prefix in `xsl:stylesheet` element and there is AFAIK no possibility how to do it dynamically. Might be some preprocessing could be the way (xslt to create desired 2nd xslt which would be applied on input xml).

Comment: Just to know - what is this issue needed for? In my point of view prefix is not important as far as it is just a shortcut for uri.

Comment: OK. I also thought so, that using xsl1.0 this is not possible.